# ImageIO.read concurrency

Tags: scala, concurrency, actor, javax.imageio

I would like to know how I can make sure the following method is safe when it's called concurrently. When It's called from two different actors, the images can get mixed up and saved under an the method will return different image for a given url.

```
def readFromURL(url: URL): Box[(Array[Byte], String, String)] = {
  tryo {
    val image = ImageIO.read(url)
    val mimeType = url.openConnection().getContentType()
    val imageType = mimeType.split("/")(1)
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ImageIO.write(image, imageType, baos)
    val byteArray = baos.toByteArray()
    val fileName = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(byteArray)
    baos.flush()
    baos.close()
    (byteArray, mimeType, fileName)
  }
}
```

Comment: "When It's called from two different actors, the images can get mixed up" - Are you asking if this is the case, or is this what you experience?

Comment: @haraldK it's what I experience. It happens a lot when I increase the concurrency. Maybe it's something else but I really get the feeling that where it could be coming from if a temp file or something like that is created at some point.

Comment: Strange... I voted for @monkjack's answer, as I can't see anything wrong (I'm no Scala expert, but the code looks very much like Java). Are the URLs always different?

Comment: @haraldK yes always ;) well monkjack could be right I'm also going to try with ImageIO.setUseCache(false)

Comment: @haraldK ok thanks I have updated

Comment: Still same symptoms? You should probably update title and tags as well.

Comment: @haraldK it didn't happen again for now I'll close it if it stays that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks thread safe to me and org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils is advertised as thread safe too.